# Excel If or statement with multiple conditions not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I added this formula to get values positive values instead of negative but this condition is not working for me true part is working but the false part is being ignored

[image]

Comment: can you give an example where it's not working? Everything looks correct to me

Comment: C4 in the image is current assets, so it should do D4-E4, which it is doing

Comment: No, F4 is currently showing D4-E4

Comment: @gulsher - your formula is correct and works as intended.

Comment: ohh sorry my bad i have added wrong value sorry for inconvenience

Comment: if the problem is solved, u may close this question..